# Get Aggregation of Mutliple Fileds in Elastic search

Tags: java, elasticsearch, aggregate

I am querying ElasticSearch using Java API. Now i am able to query aggregation in one field. Its code given below.

```
SearchResponse res = client.prepareSearch("myindex").addAggregation(AggregationBuilders.terms("aggs").field("item_type"))
                .setQuery(QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery("item_name:dell"))
                .setSize(10).execute().actionGet();
```

Here i need to add one more aggregation field along with item_type like brand etc.
How do i add more fields along with item_type.How do i do that with java API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another aggregation at top level

```
SearchResponse res = client.prepareSearch("myindex").addAggregation(AggregationBuilders.terms("aggs").field("item_type")).addAggregation(AggregationBuilders.terms("aggs2).field("item_type2))
            .setQuery(QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery("item_name:dell"))
            .setSize(10).execute().actionGet();
```